# Confidence interval of bootstrapped difference of means

Tags: bootstrap, simulation, normality-assumption

I am attempting to calculate a confidence interval for a difference in 2 populations by means of bootstrapping in order to compare this to an interval calculated via normal theory.

I am getting stuck in the following place.

Under the assumption that $\bar{x}_{bootstrap} - \bar{x} = \bar{x} - \mu$ it therefore stands to reason that $\mu = 2\bar{x} -\bar{x}_{bootstrap}$

So in order to calculate a 95% confidence interval via bootstrapping  with 1000 bootstrapped differences in means, $\bar{x}_{bootstrap}$ would have to be at the 975th and 25th positions.

My only issue is that when I assume $\mu = \bar{x} -\bar{x}_{bootstrap}$, the bootstrapped interval is far more similar to the interval calculated via normal theory.

In conclusion, what how should the estimates for our upper and lower bounds be calculated when bootstrapping a difference of 2 means?

```
bootstrap.t.test <- function(sample.x,sample.y,number) {

   pooled_sample = c(sample.x,sample.y)

   boots <-matrix(NA,nrow=number,ncol=length(pooled_sample))
   for(i in 1:number){
      boot <-sample(pooled_sample,size=length(pooled_sample),replace=TRUE)
      boots[i,] <- boot
   }

   bs_means.x = apply(boots[,1:length(pooled_sample)/2],1,mean)
   bs_means.y = apply(boots[,((length(pooled_sample)/2)+1):length(pooled_sample)],1,mean)

   bs_diffs = bs_means.x - bs_means.y

   return(bs_diffs)

}
conf.interval <- function(bootstraps,level,summary_stat){

lower.alpha = (1-level)/2
upper.alpha = 1-lower.alpha

sorted.means = sort(bootstraps,decreasing=FALSE)
upper.error = sorted.means[length(sorted.means)*(upper.alpha)] - summary_stat
lower.error = sorted.means[length(sorted.means)*(lower.alpha)] - summary_stat

upper.bound = summary_stat + abs(lower.error)
lower.bound = summary_stat - abs(upper.error)

paste(level," CI: [",lower.bound," , ",upper.bound,"]",sep="")


}
```

Comment: What you track each time you take a bootstrap sample is $\bar{x}_A-\bar{x}_B$, the difference in means of your two groups. It does not appear that you are doing so, and I am wondering why not.

Comment: @Dave I'll post my R code. I'm having no issue in getting the bootstrapped samples, just issues with getting CI.